# Retraining a MobileNet with large images

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

I'm trying to retrain the Tensorflow for Poets MobileNets tutorial with my own images (800x600px, colour so I think x3) and I think the issue is that I'm using images that are too big.

I've gotten to this page in the tutorial
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#7

and everything has worked fine, but once I put my new image path and image size in, it gives me this error:
ERROR:tensorflow:The Mobilenet input size should be '224', '192', '160', or '128',
 but found '480000' for architecture 'mobilenet_0.50_480000'
ERROR:tensorflow:Did not recognize architecture flag

The tutorial says

> Input image resolution: 128,160,192, or 224px. Unsurprisingly, feeding in a higher resolution image takes more processing time, but results in better classification accuracy.
>
> The relative size of the model as a fraction of the largest MobileNet: 1.0, 0.75, 0.50, or 0.25.

And you are supposed to enter that information with this code:

```
    IMAGE_SIZE=224
    ARCHITECTURE="mobilenet_0.50_${IMAGE_SIZE}"
```

Is this a limit of the mobilenet? Can it not do bigger images? One other possibility is that my images are all pngs and the tutorial is all jpegs, but I don't see anywhere to specify filetype.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated

Comment: You can certainly do bigger images with mobilenet. In fact you can use the pretrained mobilenet with larger images without retraining, it's designed to be image size agnostic (though if feature sizes change you might get worse results). The flags are just parameters in tensorflow. I'm not 100% sure of the answer here, but you appear to be looking in the right place to me.

Comment: @David-Parks just realised there was another line above that- the error makes me think it's definitely a size issue, but I can't believe I'm the first person to ever try bigger images with this so I'm going to keep searching. The full error was: 'ERROR:tensorflow:The Mobilenet input size should be '224', '192', '160', or '128',
 but found '480000' for architecture 'mobilenet_0.50_480000'
ERROR:tensorflow:Did not recognize architecture flag'.

Comment: That sounds like it's looking for one of the pretrained networks which were of those sizes. We use mobilenet, but unfortunately, we rebuilt the network under own own framework, so I don't know the original code particularly well. The existing code may be geared towards inference only and require you to make some changes to perform training. Though, I don't know for sure. The model architecture certainly is capable of variable sizes, that much I can say with confidence.